# How to automatically check/ensure if all external libraries are included lib folder in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to submit my homework assignments in a form of zipped eclipse project folders. I just lost a few points in an otherwise solid program because some external libraries were missing in my submission.
I looked in my project folder and cannot figure out what those libraries were. Is there an option in eclipse that would automatically copy all external jars to the lib folder?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absolute best thing you can do is to test it.  Open a new Eclipse workspace and import the project just as if you were receiving it from a student.

Also make sure you're not configuring your project to use any truly external libraries that are outside of the project folder, otherwise if you're still on the same machine, you may not notice that there's an issue.  Store them in a "lib" folder underneath the project instead.  (Do this from the start, rather than needing to worry about copying them in later.  Do you have a specific need to be using external libraries in the first place?)

Alternatively, if your instructor is open to it - see if you can use a dependency management mechanism, such as Apache Maven.

Comment: That's the problem. I looked through my folder and don't see any truly external libraries. If I were explicitly importing any external libraries I would would ensure to copy them to the lib folder.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is shown on the "Java Build Path", specifically on the "Libraries" tab?

Comment: Thank's for your help. If i don't get any simpler answer by tomorrow I will assume that there is no other way but to test it with a different eclipse instance and will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks - but were you able to see what's on the "Java Build Path"?  (Right-click the project, choose Properties.)